# How can I convert regular angles into isometric angles?

Tags: xna, isometric, angle

[image]

I'm currently working on an isometric game and I need some help converting regular angles properly to work with the isometric scaled angles. I've shown a rough example of how the same angle is different when put into an isometric perspective.

Basically, if I have an angle in degrees or radians, I'm looking for a way to convert it into the same angle, just with the isometric skew. Any help or a point in the right direction would be very helpful.

btw, I may need to point out that as I'm working with pixel art, the isometric angle isn't the standard 30 degrees and is instead 26.6.

Answer (score 0):

You should work independently from the world and its representation...

I think is better to define your world with the default base, (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)... and  work the logic in that base....

and then when you need to visualize it, you only have to render with an isometric projection.

Comment: That'd actually end up being much more work than what I'm proposing. The reasons I need the angle to angle translation has to do with the setting up the initial range that other angle checks have to fall within. If I understand what you're saying, I'd have to have two separate sets of coordinates for all my world objects for the sole purpose of figuring out angles -_-;;

Comment: you only have the world coordinates in your update method... the isometric projected coordinates are calculated transforming world coordinates to isometric through a matrix transform in the draw method...

Comment: I'm working on a 2D sprite based game so the only matrix transformations I'm currently running if at all, is for zooming and rotating the camera. Everything in game is positioned based on the world coordinates and is already in it's isometric form. If I understand what you're suggesting properly, I don't think I could do it without being able to reverse transform all the coordinates into where they would be in a non isometric state.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but I think you could follow these steps to do that:

```
Start with a vector on the first image.
Rotate it to the isometric version.
Project the resulting vector to the view plane.
Take the angle of the resulting vector.
```